# How to access elements of an integer array

Tags: assembly

I am a beginner in assembly language, I am bit confused about how an array is addressed.

Suppose there is an array(named "list") of 100 integers(4 bytes each) stored at a location(say 0x10010010). how do I find the address of its elements, like list[3] or list[16]?

Also, how do i write an assembly directive to specify the memory for this array?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at compiler output to see how they do it, for any ISA you have a C compiler for. [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116).  If you have a specific ISA and assembler syntax in mind (e.g. x86-64 NASM), a more specific answer is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You said it yourself; each integer is 4 bytes long. They are stored contiguously in memory. `list` is the address of the first of them (zeroth, to be precise). *Assuming that you use zero based indexing when you say `list[3]`*, the address of `list[3]` will be `list + 3*4`, or `list+12`. In general, the formula is `base+index*4`, where `base` is the address of the array, and index goes from 0 to 99. 4 comes from the integer size.

To use your example, if the array is at 0x10010010, then list[3] would be at 0x1001001C, list[16] would be at 0x10010050.

As for the assembly, you didn't tell us which CPU/emulator are you using. There's more than one flavor of assembly out there.

Some types of assembly, notably Intel x86 and ARM, have built-in logic for index scaling for accessing integer arrays - the CPU will multiply the index (stored in a register) by 4 for you.